# Not able to Start/Stop Spark Worker from Remote Machine

Tags: mapreduce, cluster-computing, apache-spark

I have two machines A and B. I am trying to run Spark Master on machine A and Spark Worker on machine B.
I have set machine B's host name in `conf/slaves` in my Spark directory.

When I am executing `start-all.sh` to start master and workers, I am getting below message on console:

```sh
abc@abc-vostro:~/spark-scala-2.10$ sudo sh bin/start-all.sh 
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
starting spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /home/abc/spark-scala-2.10/bin/../logs/spark-root-spark.deploy.master.Master-1-abc-vostro.out
13/09/11 14:54:29 WARN spark.Utils: Your hostname, abc-vostro resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 1XY.1XY.Y.Y instead (on interface wlan2)
13/09/11 14:54:29 WARN spark.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
Master IP: abc-vostro
cd /home/abc/spark-scala-2.10/bin/.. ; /home/abc/spark-scala-2.10/bin/start-slave.sh 1 spark://abc-vostro:7077
xyz@1XX.1XX.X.X's password: 
xyz@1XX.1XX.X.X: bash: line 0: cd: /home/abc/spark-scala-2.10/bin/..: No such file or directory
xyz@1XX.1XX.X.X: bash: /home/abc/spark-scala-2.10/bin/start-slave.sh: No such file or directory
```

Master is started but worker is failed to start.

I have set `xyz@1XX.1XX.X.X` in `conf/slaves` in my Spark directory.

Can anyone help me to resolve this? This is probably something I'm missing any configuration on my end.

However when I create Spark Master and Worker on same machine, It is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you copied all Spark's files at the worker too? Also you need to setup password less access b/w master and worker.

Answer (score 0):

Here were steps I would follow,

- Setting up public key authentication over SSH
- Checking /etc/spark/conf.dist/spark-env.sh
- scp this to your computer B from computer A (master)
- Set conf/slaves, hostname for computer B
- ./start-all.sh

For standalone cluster mode, you may set these option in spark-env.sh.
For example,

- export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
- export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1
- export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=4G

Answer (score -1):

see SSH ACCESS,  in hadoop multinode cluster setup by michael. just like that .... will solve ur probs..

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.